# Probability Independence

Tags: probability

I learned at school that to visualize two events A and B as independent, I could interpret event A and B as a Venn Diagram where the two circles are disjoint. If they overlapped the events are dependent.

Let's have a look at this example:

Assume:

P(Thunder) = 1/2

P(Rain) = 1/3

P(Rain and Thunder) = 1/6

P(Not Rain and Not Thunder) = 1/3

Question:

P(Thunder And Rain) = P(Thunder) * P(Rain) = 1/2 * 1/3 = 1/6

So, P(Rain) and P(Thunder) are independent even though they are not disjoint.

Should I assume that the visual interpretation is wrong?

Comment: "to visualize two events A and B as independent, I could interpret event A and B as a Venn Diagram where the two circles are disjoint." NOT. AT. ALL. You may want to sue your teachers if they told you that.

Comment: When the events are disjoint they are $\textit{mutually exclusive}$, not independent. In fact, if the events both have positive probability, they will NEVER be independent if they're disjoint: $\mathbb P(A \cap B) = \mathbb P(\emptyset) = 0 \neq \mathbb P(A)\cdot \mathbb P(B)$.

Comment: Then, I should only stick to the definition of independence being P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B) and forget about the relationship between the Venn Diagram and Independence.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that disjoint events are independent, is wrong!
Where did you learn this rubbish?
If events are independent, we have
$$ P(A)P(B)= P(A\cap B)$$
If they are disjoint, we have always that the RHS is zero. So, no to your assumption.

Comment: Thanks. The point of school is to learn and unlearn :(